# How to load a Pandas DataFrame according to a Dash Callback?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I have the following function which associates a dropdown selection to a file path:

```
def origin_func():

return html.Div(                                                                  
    children=[                                                                    
        dcc.Markdown('Select country'),                              
        dcc.Dropdown(                                                             
            id='origin_div',                                                      
            options=[{'label': 'Malta', 'value': './data/malta.csv'}, {'label': 'Japan', 'value': './data/japan.csv'}],
            value='./data/malta.csv'                                   
        )                                                                         
    ]                                                                             
)
```

Through a callback, I can turn this selection into Pandas DataFrame:

```
@app.callback(                          
    Output('country_table', 'children'),
    Input('origin_div', 'value')        
)                                       
def countrytable(origin_div):           
    df = pd.read_csv(origin-div)        
    return df
```

Question is, how could I pass a Pandas DataFrame, stored into a Dash variable ('country_table'), into a layout function, such as :

```
    def destination_func():
            children=[
                dcc.Markdown('Select country of destination'),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='destination_div',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Destination'].drop_duplicates()],
                    value=df['Destination'].drop_duplicates()[0]
                )
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two main ways of doing this.

1. Make the output from your `countrytable` callback function the place you want the dataframe to end up.
2. Pass the dataframe into something else to hold it, and retrieve it from that place when you need it later.

It looks like you're doing the second option here. You could output the dataframe with

`df.to_dict(orient='records')`

and then, when you need it later, read it back in and do

`df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_arg)`

The function that is reading in the `dict` to turn into a dataframe would take the `Output` from the first callback as either an `Input` or `State` argument.

Edit:

The callback you'd need to add for the second option looks something like this:

```py
@app.callback(                          
    Output('whatever-component-in-your-layout', 'whatever-prop'),
    Input('country_table', 'children')        
)                                       
def countrytable(stored_df):           
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stored_df)
    return df
```

Comment: Hi @coralvanda, since 2d way doesn't work -- whatever I put as 'dict_arg' I have the following error: "NameError: name 'dict_arg' is not defined"  -- how would you do the first option?

Comment: Added an example. Let me know if you still need some help.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have the following error: "NameError: name 'df' is not defined". The idea of what I'm trying to do is to be able to select a csv and load it as a DataFrame through a Dropdown list in Dash. A full working minimal example would be a great help since I saw various people on the web struggling on this without finding a solution.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: By attempting to provide a minimal example to point out the issues I was facing in regard to this question, I thought of a satisfying solution to solve it. Unfortunately, it brought another issue that I formulated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432487/how-to-dynamically-set-a-default-value-in-a-dcc-dropdown-when-options-come-from).